# Grab data values from Row with max value

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

First step I do is find the column row with the max value through `=MAX(A1:a10)`.

Let's say it's A7 that has the max value.

Once I have that value, I would like some data from the rest of row 7 to be grabbed. For instance if A7 is the max value, I'd like to grab the values from B7, C7 and E7 automatically.

How do I do this? Take into account the row with max value is constantly changing.

Comment: I should mention that I would like B7,C7 and E7 all in there own cells. So the formulas can be for each individual one for ease

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned what you would like to so with the three values mentioned, but maybe try:

```
 =index(B:BB,match(max(A1:A10),A:A,0))
```

or perhaps:

```
=index(B:B,match(max(A1:A10),A:A,0))&index(C:C,match(max(A1:A10),A:A,0))&index(E:E,match(max(A1:A10),A:A,0))
```

or perhaps:

```
=index(query(A:E,"select B,C,E"),match(max(A1:A10),A:A,0))
```